# python Can I assess the binary message in websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, async-await

So websockets I'm looking for is a chat of live-streaming.

[image]

and when I click the Messages tab, I can see Binary Messages are back and forth. 
Some of these are real messages, but some of are not. I don't know what those are. Maybe status checks?

[image]

What I am wondering is, am I possible to gather these binary messages using `websockets`?

I'm not even sure whether this is possible. Below doesn't work. 
I think this should print something when someone chats.

```
import websockets
import asyncio

async def access_chat():
  uri = "wss://chat-af7e4856.afreecatv.com:8001/Websocket/freesias"
  async with websockets.connect(uri, subprotocols=['chat'], ping_interval=None) as websocket:
    content = await websocket.recv()
    print(content)
```

Comment: The image shows that the client sends several messages before the server sends something back. You're not sending anything in your Python program.

Comment: It's a binary protocol specific to the application, you need to know that protocol to decode it.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, then how can I gather those binary messages in Python? I'll just use what I know and what I need. No need to know that specific protocol.

Comment: Why do this in Python? Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark.